# compare file with other 14 files

Tags: c#

I want to compare file1 with another 14 files one at each time.  What I want to is read file1 and read other file from the the 14 files the then find the number of match (words) between two files 
compute the number of words for each another 14 file (one in each time)

I have tried the code below:

```
        static void Main()
        {
            StreamReader objReader = new StreamReader(@"c:\basic_source.txt");
            string filepath = "";
            ArrayList arrText = new ArrayList();
            while (filepath != null)
            {
                filepath = objReader.ReadLine();
                if (filepath != null)
                    arrText.Add(filepath);

            }
            objReader.Close();

            //string path;
            //path = filepath;
            // Read the file and display it line by line.
            int found;
            int count = 0;
           string [] cc;
            int basic_source_attr_no = 20;
            float simi_degree;
            string textData = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\expermentaldata\s3\attributes.txt");
            int cnt = (WordCounting.CountWords1(textData));
            string[] content = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\expermentaldata\s3\attributes.txt");
            //int cnt = content.Count();



            string[] mastercontent = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\basic_source.txt");

            foreach (string con in content)
            {

                if (mastercontent.Contains(con))
                {
                    found = 1;
                    count = count + found;

                }


            }

            simi_degree = (basic_source_attr_no + cnt) / count;

            try
            {

                simi_degree = (basic_source_attr_no + cnt) / count;

            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("external attribute no      similar attributes    simi_degree      ");
            Console.WriteLine("---------------------------------------------------------------");

            Console.WriteLine("  {0}                             {1}                {2}        ", cnt, count, simi_degree);

            Console.ReadLine();

        }

    }

    public static class WordCounting
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Count words with Regex.
        /// </summary>
        public static int CountWords1(string s)
        {
            MatchCollection collection = Regex.Matches(s, @"[\S]+");
            return collection.Count;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest waiting until you have something a little more specific to ask.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want to do is compare 2 files, and count the words that are the same between them.  I am going to attempt to answer this (you don't have a question, and the information that is there is hard to understand).

The code that you currently have posted compares lines of text and not words.

What you should do is create a method to return a list of words for a given string (lets call it GetWordsFromString()).
then for each file you have, read it in, call the GetWordsFromString().  Then take the words for you master list, iterate through each one and see if it exists in your secondary list.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little too broad and a bit unclear, but take a look at [DiffPlex](http://diffplex.codeplex.com/) to get you started.